# Copy Files based on year it was created using powershell

Tags: powershell

I am new to powershell. I have a requirement to list and copy files that were created in a particular year, because the number of files in the folder exceeds millions.

I tried getting the file names of 2021 like below:

```
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath "C:\Users\abhi.y.user" -Recurse -File | 
Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -ge "01/01/2021" -and $_.CreationTime -le "31/12/2021" }
```

But it gives me output that powershell Cannot convert value "31/12/2021" to type
"System.DateTime.

And once I gets any output, I plan to copy those files, ( The output of previous code ) like below:

```
Copy-Item "C:\Users\abhi.y.user" -Destination "I:\Backups"
```

But this is wrong, as I can't figure out how to pass the output of first command to this one. Can anyone help me to understand how to accomplish this?

Comment: `... |Where-Object { $_.CreationTime.Year -eq 2021 }`

Comment: Thanks, seems working. And how to pass the output of this command to the copy code?

Comment: `... |Where-Object { $_.CreationTime.Year -eq 2021 } | Copy-Item -Destination "I:\Backups"`. -Based on Mathias comment.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `Year` property on the `CreationTime` property value to see if the year is correct:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath "C:\Users\abhi.y.user" -Recurse -File 
$filesFrom2021 = $files | Where-Object { $_.CreationTime.Year -eq 2021 }
```

You can pipe the output directly to `Copy-Item`:

```
$filesFrom2021 |Copy-Item -Destination "I:\backups\"
```

PowerShell will automatically bind the value of the `FullName` property on each file object to the `-LiteralPath` parameter of `Copy-Item` exactly as if you'd executed `Copy-Item -LiteralPath "C:\Users\abhi.y.user\path\to\matching\file.txt" -Destination "I\backups\"`

Comment: This seems nice. Thanks. Is there a way to store the output of $files on disk, so that when I rerun the script, for say 2019, I don't have to calculate $file again. The folder has at least 15 million files, and running $files = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath "C:\Users\abhi.y.user" -Recurse -File everytime will take at least 30 minutes.

Comment: @No-power-777 what makes you think that reading a file with 15 million entries will take less time?